# GridUnload - free Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

We've found when using GridUnload  and grid load again, toolbar search is removed complete :

This row is deleted complete.

```
<tr role = "row" class = "ui-toolbar-search" style = "display: table-row;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! The reason was the property `ftoolbar` which stay set to `true` which used to detect whether the filter toolbar already exist or not. [The fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/bec891e15f8e03ea8f5bfc4ab350257c409b2065) solves the problem. Please reload free jqGrid, which you use, from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).